# Will this method for centering my H1 cause issues later on?

Tags: html, css

I plan on trying to roughly re-create the [popular tier list website](https://tiermaker.com/create/types-of-drinks-584882) as an interface for an exercise on learning the draggable and droppable jquery features. Right now I'm just trying to make a single tier row to see how it's done before I actually start. Is the way I centered the h1 in the div inherently wrong? It keeps its size and works fine but it seems like I'm missing something, in either how the text is being centered or how the colored box is being made.

Here is what the tier looks like.
[image: Here is what the tier looks like.]

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  margin-top: 20%;
  display: block;
  height: 130px;
  width: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 3px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-right: none;
  background-color: rgb(55, 55, 55);
}

header div {
  background-color: rgb(191, 57, 57);
  position: relative;
  width: 140px;
  height: 124px;
  display: block;
  border-right: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header div h1 {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 40px 35px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <div>
      <h1>Rank</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I mean, at least on my machine the text is not actually horizontally centered. So I guess you could consider that a problem. The h1 is inheriting some sort of left offset, so the margin needs to actually be `40px 30px`. But if it works for you and not for me, there's your "issue later on" -- our systems are inherently rendering it differently.

Comment: Yeah it's not perfect on mine either, I didn't want to spend the time getting it perfect before I knew if this method was just incorrect to do or not. I figured how it looks got the point across. The 40 30 looks much better, though.

Comment: Why use absolute positioning for the H1? Generally any place you use absolute or fixed positioning are where you're going to run into issues in the future. Are things supposed to live to the right of that heading on the menu bar? How's this supposed to scale to small screens like phones?

Comment: If I take off the absolute positioning, the red box jumps down to where the top of the box is just a few pixels above "rank" and the bottom of the box is below the grey rectangle entirely. Yes there will be things to the right eventually, but this file was purely for making a singular sample row. As far as the phone screen, I have not learned about responsive design yet and the main point of this was to setup for learning the 2 jquery features.

Comment: So take off absolute, set margin to 0 30px and padding-top to 40px. Generally, don't use absolute positioning in modern design like ... ever.

Answer (score 1):

Will your method cause problems down the road? That's a definite "maybe".

Flex and grid are much more mainstream methods of doing what you are hoping to accomplish and will contribute to a responsive design.

This method uses `flex` to accomplish the same:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  margin-top: 20%;
  display: block;
  height: 130px;
  width: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 3px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-right: none;
  background-color: rgb(55, 55, 55);
}

header div {
  background-color: rgb(191, 57, 57);
  position: relative;
  width: 140px;
  height: 124px;
  /* display: block; */
  border-right: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;                /* added */
}

header div h1 {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 2em;
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* margin: 40px 35px; */
  display: flex;                /* added */
  justify-content: center;      /* added */
  align-items: center;          /* added */
  width: 100%;                  /* added */
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <header>
    <div>
      <h1>Rank</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```